# .Net interfaces inheritance compilation

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

Why is this :

```
public interface IServiceRecherche<T, U>
                    where T : IEntite
                    where U : ICritereRecherche
{
    IList<T> Rechercher(U critere);
}

public interface IServiceRechercheUnite :
                        IServiceRecherche<IUnite, ICritereRechercheUnite>,

{}
```

different from :

```
public interface IServiceRechercheUnite                             
{
    IList<IUnite> Rechercher(ICritereRechercheUnite critere);
}
```

when compiled ?

Applications that were compiled with the first interface could not recognize the second one. I know they are not the same in the code but in the end during execution why aren't they the same ?

Comment: "could not recognize" - what do you mean with "recognize" in this context?

Comment: I use reflection to bind the interface to its implementation and it couldn't find the proper implementation.

Comment: @Vincent: Please state the namespaces of your two interfaces. Also, please show how you wrote a class that implements one of the interfaces and explain which assembly with which one of your interfaces you referenced when compiling that class.

Comment: To clarify, I had the first interface which works nicely. I didn't want the inheritance anymore and changed it to the second one but when put in production, it failed. I just wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

From the point of CLR, these are different types, because the first one is a closed-generic type, inherited from `IServiceRecherche<T, U>`.

> but in the end during execution why aren't they the same

The reason is the same, as in the case of:

```
public MyClass1
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public MyClass2
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

They're just a different type declarations, in spite of  having similar members declarations.

CLR can't think this way: "Ah, MyClass1 and MyClass2 are identical. Let's consider them as the same type".

Comment: Aren't generics compiled to their proper final type at execution ? (I have no idea at all)

Comment: @Vincent: yes, closed generic type `IServiceRecherche<IUnite, ICritereRechercheUnite>` will be instantiated at run-time. But it doesn't matter. `IServiceRechercheUnite : IServiceRecherche<IUnite, ICritereRechercheUnite>` and `IServiceRechercheUnite` will point to the different type objects.

Comment: Oh I get what you mean. Both doesn't exist at the same time. I changed the first to the second. I csomewhat clarified it on the post above

Answer (score 0):

You could however use [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckTyping) to "cast" one instance into another. For this you will need a class representing your duck:

```
public class LooksLikeAnIServiceRecherche : IServiceRecherche<IUnite, ICritereRechercheUnite>
{
    private readonly dynamic _duck;

    public LooksLikeAnIServiceRecherche (dynamic duck)
    {
        this._duck = duck;
    }

    public IList<IUnite> Rechercher(ICritereRechercheUnite critere)
    {
        return this._duck.Rechercher(critere);
    }
}
```

The call to the `Rechercher`-method is validated at runtime, not at compile time, thus preventing the compiler error you received.

Using that code is simple:

```
IServiceRechercheUnite rechercheUnite;
var serviceRecherche = new LooksLikeAnIServiceRecherche(rechercheUnite);
```

For more information on how to utilize the `dynamic`-keyword see [MSDN: dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: I just wonder why they are executed differently. I reverted to the first interface. I didn't need a way to prevent it but thanks nonetheless